# Error:attempt to perform arithmetic on a nil value (field '?') while assigning value to a table

Tags: lua

```
 --An assembly in lua

    registerA = 0 --Primary Register(Default mem used by all programs)
    registerB = 0 --Secondary Register(Default mem used by  programs that need 2nd operand)
    registerCounter = 1 --Current register position
    registerOpcode = {}  --+-Holds the decoded assembly
    registerOperand = {} --+
    opcode = true        --Swich between oprand and opcode
    error = ""
    
    opcodes = {
      "NUL",
      "ADD",
      "SUB",
      "MUL",
      "DIV",
      "JMP",
      "LDA",
      "LDB",
      "STA",
      "STB"
    }
    
    
    function decodeOpcode(val)
      for key,instruction in pairs(opcodes) do
        if instruction == val then
          return key
        end
      end
      error = "Bad instruction["..math.ceil(registerCounter/2).."]"
      return 0
    end
    
    function decode()
      file = io.open("main.assem","r")
      for instruction in file:read("*a"):gmatch("%w+") do
        if error ~= "" then
          break
        end
        if opcode then
          registerOpcode[registerCounter] = decodeOpcode(instruction)
        else
          registerOperand[registerCounter] = tonumber(instruction)
          registerCounter = registerCounter + 1 
        end
        opcode = not opcode
      end
      if not opcode then
        error = "Bad instruction pair["..math.floor(registerCounter).."]"
      end
      file:close()
    end
    
    function cpu()
      if registerOpcode[registerCounter] == 1 then
        
      elseif registerOpcode[registerCounter] == 2 then
        registerA = registerA + registerOperand[registerCounter]
      elseif registerOpcode[registerCounter] == 3 then
        registerA = registerA - registerOperand[registerCounter]
      elseif registerOpcode[registerCounter] == 4 then
        registerA = registerA * registerOperand[registerCounter]
      elseif registerOpcode[registerCounter] == 5 then
        registerA = math.floor( registerA / registerOperand[registerCounter] )
      elseif registerOpcode[registerCounter] == 6 then
        registerCounter = registerOperand[registerCounter] - 1
      elseif registerOpcode[registerCounter] == 7 then
        registerA = registerOperand[registerCounter]
      elseif registerOpcode[registerCounter] == 8 then
        registerB = registerOperand[registerCounter]
      elseif registerOpcode[registerCounter] == 9 then
        registerOpcode[registerOperand[registerCounter]] = registerA
--> This is the line
      elseif registerOpcode[registerCounter] == 10 then
        registerOpcode[registerOperand] = registerB
      else
        error = "Bad register["..i.."]"
      end
      registerCounter = registerCounter + 1
    end
    
    decode()
    
    registerCounter = 1
    
    while error == "" and registerOpcode[registerCounter] ~= nil do
      cpu()
    end
    
    if error == "" then
      for i=1,#registerOpcode do
        print(registerOpcode[i]..","..registerOperand[i])
      end
    end
    
    if error ~= "" then
      print("Error:"..error)
    end
    
    print(registerOpcode[7])
    
    
    os.exit()
```

I am tring to assigning to table registerOperand with  `registerOpcode[registerOperand[registerCounter]] = registerA`
But when ever i try to assing to new key it throws error
I checked every variable inside the brackets. None of them are `nil`. Just the table at index is `nil` which I'm trying to assign value of `registerA`
It doent throw errors when I assign value to an existing key.

Create a code main.assem

```
LDA 15
STA 3
```

This sould store value at index 3

I though lua doesnt support nested square brackets or its a bug. But when I tried simulate similar environment separately it works with no issue.

Comment: Which line is the error at?

Comment: Its 9th if in cpu function

Comment: Create main.assem wth "LDA 5 STA 4". And let the magic happen. Theres no erro when im overwrting existing key.

Comment: next time please post a [mcve]. your code and input did not produce the error you say

Answer (score 0):

So I ran your code with the proposed `LDA 15 STA 3` which triggers your bad register message. This causes an error for concatenating a global nil value `i` caused by  `error = "Bad register["..i.."]"`

`i` is nil inside `cpu()`!

So I removed this error and changed to the second suggestion `LDA 5 STA 4`

Now I got the following error

> 97: attempt to concatenate a nil value (field '?')

Caused by  `print(registerOpcode[i]..","..registerOperand[i])` for `i` being `3`

First you run decode which gives you

`registerOpcode = {7, 9}` and `registerOperand = {5, 4}`

In the first call of cpu you assign `7` to `registerA`.
In the second call you assign `registerA` to `registerOpcode[4]`

So now `registerOpCode = {7, 9, nil, 4}`

Then you run a numeric for loop over registerOpcode that indexes `registerOpcode[3]` which is `nil`.

I don't know how and where you faced the quoted error

> Error:attempt to perform arithmetic on a nil value (field '?')

But it is not caused by the code/input you provided. The mentioned line contains an assignment. This cannot cause an error for arithmetic operations.

Comment: I think I should redo it from scratch. Since i got a better algorithm idea.Using one table instead of 2 and adding a LBL(label opcode)

Comment: Also the program works fine if i use a constant instead of variable even if i create new key. I didn't get other errors you received. I guess its random on different system. Better do it from scratch.

Comment: no errors are not random. if `i` is a nil value you cannot concatenate it. no matter what system you use. for the provided input your code will produce the errors I mentioned. they have to

Comment: If it gives me issue in that algorithm too. I am gonna shift to cpp or java. And  if those works, I am breaking up with lua.

Comment: don't blame Lua if you implement faulty code. ;-) the error is always in front of the computer

Comment: If its my fault,shouldnt i get error in cpp or java too.

Comment: I didnt gave excuse. Just shared my feeling. I started from sceatch because i thoight my code messed up. So thank you for helping me and sorry if i offended you. I didnt ment to offend lua. The breakup was just a joke. I love lua. Thats why im coding in lua instead of java,cpp or python.